# Returning NOBODY because of SkipAdminCheck

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api-java-client

> [INFO] Oct 06, 2016 11:24:54 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.AppEngineAuthentication$AppEngineAuthenticator authenticate
>   [INFO] INFO: Returning NOBODY because of SkipAdminCheck.

Seems this error is produced by TaskQueue.

```
    Queue qu = QueueFactory.getQueue(qname);
    qu.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/task/"+qname)
        .payload("{\"token\":\"asdf1234\"}","UTF-8")
        .method(TaskOptions.Method.POST)
        .header("Host", ModulesServiceFactory.getModulesService().getVersionHostname(null,null))
```

Any suggestions how to fix it? Sure I googled, Google found just 3 pages about, and two first is about adding. As you see above I have added following but the code still produce messages into the log:

```
.header("Host", ModulesServiceFactory.getModulesService().getVersionHostname(null,null))
```

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10457

Comment: @GAEfan I read this link. As in comment #26 I have alrady added that line and the result is #27: "This problem is still present on 1.9.40" is actual for me too